# mongodb Embedded document search on parent and child field

Tags: mongodb

I have a nested embedded document CompanyProduct below is structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d213c5ddbb1912343a8ca3"),
    "CompanyID" : 90449,
    "Name" : Company1,
    "CompanyDepartment" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53d213c5ddbb1912343a8ca4")
            "DepartmentID" : 287,
            "DepartmentName" : "Stores",
            "DepartmentInventory" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("53b7b92eecdd765430d763bd"),
                    "ProductID" : 1,
                    "ProductName" : "abc",
                    "Quantity" : 100
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("53b7b92eecdd765430d763bd"),
                    "ProductID" : 2,
                    "ProductName" : "xyz",
                    "Quantity" : 1
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
}
```

There can be N no of companies and each company can have N number of departments and each department can have N number of products.

I want to do a search to find out a particular product quantity under a particular company

I tried below query but it does not work. It returns all the products for the specific company, the less than 20 condition doesn't work.

```
db.CompanyProduct.find({$and : [{"CompanyDepartment.DepartmentInventory.Quantity":{$lt :20}},{"CompanyID":90449}]})
```

How should the query be?

Comment: is CompanyProduct is your collection name sub document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching from companyProduct's sub documents. So it will return you companyProduct whole document, it is NoSQL database , some how we do not need to normalize the collection , but your case it has to be normalize , like if you want to EDIT/DELETE any sub document and if there are thousand or millions of sub document then what will you do ... You need to make other collection with the name on CompanyDepartment and companyProduct collection should be

```
productCompany

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d213c5ddbb1912343a8ca3"),
    "CompanyID" : 90449,
    "Name" : Company1,
    "CompanyDepartment" : ['53d213c5ddbb1912343a8ca4'],
 }
```

and other collection companyDepartment

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("53d213c5ddbb1912343a8ca4")
        "DepartmentID" : 287,
        "DepartmentName" : "Stores",
        "DepartmentInventory" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("53b7b92eecdd765430d763bd"),
                "ProductID" : 1,
                "ProductName" : "abc",
                "Quantity" : 100
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("53b7b92eecdd765430d763bd"),
                "ProductID" : 2,
                "ProductName" : "xyz",
                "Quantity" : 1
            }
        ],
    }
```

after this you got array of companyDeparment' ID and only push and pull query will be used on productCompany

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and it helped me to seperate the documents and also perform a single query for retrieval

Answer (score 0):

A Solution can be

```
db.YourCollection.aggregate([
{
    $project:{
        "CompanyDepartment.DepartmentInventory":1,
        "CompanyID" : 1
    }
},{ 
    $unwind: "$CompanyDepartment"
},{ 
    $unwind: "$CompanyDepartment.DepartmentInventory"
},{    
    $match:{$and : [{"CompanyDepartment.DepartmentInventory.Quantity":{$lt :20}},{"CompanyID":90449}]}    
}

])
```

the result is

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53d213c5ddbb1912343a8ca3"),
            "CompanyID" : 90449,
            "CompanyDepartment" : {
                "DepartmentInventory" : {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("53b7b92eecdd765430d763bd"),
                    "ProductID" : 2,
                    "ProductName" : "xyz",
                    "Quantity" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```